# Writing Artisan Command - Display Data from Database

Tags: php, laravel, command, laravel-artisan

I want to write a Artisan command for my Laravel Web App.

The command should display the records from a specific table of a database.

I already created a new command called `Loginstats.php` in the Commands folder , but I'm struggling with the logic....

I think it's could be work with something in that way:

```
public function handle() {
        DB::table('logincount')->orderBy ( 'customer_id' )->chunk ( 100, function ($users) {
            foreach ($users as $user) {
                //
            }
        } );
    }
```

What do I need to do, to get the data from the database?

Is it also possible with the common artisan commands from the `Command.php` ?

Thank you!

Comment: So what do you see if you run your command?

Comment: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Class 'App\Console\Commands\DB' not found

Comment: @Trayer add `use DB` at the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since DB is a facade, you should use full namespace:

```
\DB::table...
```

Or add `use DB` to the top of the class after `namespace` clause:

```
use DB;
```